# Post hoc after a 2xN chi-squared test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I have two groups of people, and I want to determine if there's a significant difference based on their language. My data consist of word frequencies (how many times a person sayed a given word in a given time range), thus their contingency table looks like this:

[image: Contingency table]

I used the chi-squared test to compare the sums of word frequencies (vectors $x$ and $y$) and found a significant difference between the two groups (very low $p$-value). Now, I'm considering whether a post-hoc analysis is meaningful with just two groups. How can I conduct a post hoc analysis in this scenario?

Comment: Hi Alessandro. Why did you use the means, rather than the sums? The chi-square test of independence or homogeneity is meant to be used with counts, not manipulation of counts, so the p-value you got is likely incorrect. I suspect you should ask a question on what model to use to answer your research question

Comment: I really don't know why I wrote means. I used the sums (I edited the question). Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by post-hoc analysis?  Do you mean comparing individual persons?  With m+2 persons, you may run into problems of statistical power if you try an (m+2) x 2 chi-square test.

Comment: Please explain how this data was collected. Some relevant questions: What are these words? How many of them are there? What are the utterances from which the words were extracted from. Did you get one utterance from each person? ....